# Background image positioning and scaling problem

Tags: html, css

I am trying to clone the Netflix website but got stuck on the background image part. I want to copy same as the bg-image in the website but the image in netflix seems to be magnified and i am not being to achieve that through my code. The image just doesn't seem to be copied as the one in the website. [The one i want to clone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8dkp.jpg).
[What the image i code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k02Mw.jpg)

I first tried bg-size to cover, then the image gets scaled down and when i tried contain it doesn't work, then i removed the bg-size and then the image gets magnified by default values. Then, I tried using the bg-position property to copy the background; but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scale your image, you can use transform [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) CSS property (should be applied to the image element). As far as I can tell, Netflix upscales the image by a factor of 1.25 and reverses its position, moving along the Y-axis to minus 10%.

```
transform: scale(1.25) translateY(-10%);
```

You can refer to the MDN docs for more info about transform property.

Comment: When i scale and transform the image in Y , a horizontal scroll bar appears and then the content gets transformed a bit upwards leaving a white space at the bottom of the screen not covering whole of the screen 

[The problem i am getting.] https://imgur.com/a/6oS5Zeh